# Implement In-App Update Functionality

Tags: ios, titanium

for Titanium 3.1.0 and iPhone 4.2-

How To Implement In-App Update Functionality in Your iPhone/iPad App? Have you ever used an iPhone app where upon opening it, it tells you that there’s a new update compared with app store same app, after click on ok it will be updated with updated version of app. How to develop that functionality with titanium studio?